# What is the difference between MySQL and PostgreSQL in terms of writing SQL queries?

Tags: mysql, postgresql, php, phpmyadmin

Other than performance and security is there really any difference between MySQL and Postgres like SQL queries, built-in functions, procedures and so on?

I'm asking this because I'm familiar with PHP with MySQL (phpMyAdmin) but not with Postgres (phpPgAdmin)

Comment: Postgres has much more advanced SQL features than MySQL (CTEs, Window functions, recursive queries, deferrable constraints and many more), here is an overview http://www.sql-workbench.net/dbms_comparison.html

Answer (score 13, accepted):

(Regarding PostgreSQL 9.3 and MySQL 5.6, written in 2014; if you're looking at other versions, this may be outdated):

Lots more features.

- `CHECK` constraints
- True `SERIALIZABLE` isolation
- Arrays (including index support for arrays)
- Window functions (`lead`, `lag`, `row_number`, etc)
- Common table expressions (`WITH` queries) including recursive CTEs and writeable CTEs
- The `hstore` hash type and its index support
- SQL/XML support
- `json` support
- A rich set of functions and operators for many types
- Partial and function/expression indexes, including partial unique indexes and unique expression indexes
- Composite types
- User defined aggregates and operators
- Set-returning user defined functions
- User defined types
- Transactional DDL (this is *wonderful*)
- GIN and GiST indexes for complex indexing needs, including K-nearest-neighbour indexing
- [PostGIS](http://postgis.net/)
- `UNLOGGED` tables (though MyISAM meets this need in MySQL)

See [the comprehensive user manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/index.html) for details.

However:

- There are no session variables in PostgreSQL, unlike MySQL. (You can abuse GUCs for this, but not to do the same sort of things you do with MySQL session variables).
- [PostgreSQL has no `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` ("upsert")](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17267417/how-do-i-do-an-upsert-merge-insert-on-duplicate-update-in-postgresql)
- At the moment, PostgreSQL has different replication options than MySQL. MySQL has no point-in-time recovery, but PostgreSQL has no logical replication (yet, we're working on it).
- `GROUP BY ... ROLLUP` for summaries of groupings. Doing the same thing in PostgreSQL requires a union, usually over two queries over a CTE.
- PostgreSQL doesn't have a built-in event scheduler. You generally just use cron or the Windows Task Scheduler; there's also PgAgent from PgAdmin-III.

Comment: Add `CHECK` constraints and `DESC` indexes and filtered indexes and computed columns (the MariaDB variant has them only).

Comment: @ypercube Wow, really? Yep, verified. That's ... sad.

Comment: And deferred constraints.

Comment: Things that MySQL has (but not Postgres) are clustered indexes, `GROUP BY .. ROLLUP` and the `Event` (scheduler).

Comment: Other not so obvious things: you can't create a view in MySQL with a derived table in the select and you can't use dynamic SQL in functions.